# Cannot load layers into ArcGIS Viewer for Flex

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am trying to load some files into ArcGIS Viewer for Flex. My files are loaded onto the server correctly but trying to publish it into the Flex Viewer is unsuccessful.

First when I search for my layers from the server I get this warning that the program couldn't find crossdomain.xml. (see image below)

[image]

I continue to select my layers but when it tries to load I have been getting this error.

UAE Web Map layer failed to load: Fault code: Channel.Security.Error

Fault info: Security error accessing url

Fault details: Destination: DefaultHTTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're deploying your application to another server, you need to have a `crossdomain.xml` document to signify that the other application has trust to access the REST API.

This may be a good resource:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/help/index.html#//017p0000001w000000

Comment: I'm still confused. What would I need to do exactly?  pasted the URL into a web browser and I come up with this error: 

Server Error in '/ArcGIS/Services' Application.
Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine...

Comment: it needs to be /arcgis/rest/services, not simply /arcgis/services.

Comment: Here is some documentation on crossdomain.xml files:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html